# Can't get items info in IabHelper - in app billing - Android

Tags: android, eclipse, in-app-billing

When I call IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener, It does not return any item info like
 the following.

```
D/IabHelper(2233): Calling getPurchases with continuation token: null
D/IabHelper(2233): Owned items response: 0
D/IabHelper(2233): Continuation token: null
D/IabHelper(2233): Querying SKU details.
D/IabHelper(2233): queryPrices: nothing to do because there are no SKUs.
D/IabHelper(2233): Ending async operation: refresh inventory
```

I uploaded the singed apk onto GP and installed the same apk(same version and singed) in my device by using 'adb  install release.apk' command.

Also I set up items on 'In-app Products' and Gmail accounts with testing access.

I wait several hours but it still says **'queryPrices: nothing to do because there are no SKUs.'**.

I used 'in app billing' with another apk before,and It was fine.
I don't know why it doesn't work this time..

Sorry for my bad English.
Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you stumble upon this try to:

1. Upload an apk file in alpha testing or beta testing tab (but do not upload an apk file in production tab if the app should not yet be available to the public)
2. Supply all the required information (screenshots, add test users, create and activate the in app products)
3. Set the app to released.

A few hours later Google Play should return the SKUs and there details.